# 1.9.1 Order send email not work

Tags: email, ce-1.9.1.0, order-email

I have two questions, about the two buttons are unresponsive,  not work...why??why cant send email ? who can help me ~i am using 1.9.1 thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you added the cron to your server?

Comment: sorry ..what is the cron? Can you give me the detailed steps to edit..thank you
I am a newbie

Comment: i saw u gave me the page , but my english is not good, dont know which one is edit is ok????thx~

Comment: i in the cron.php edit 

$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, ‘win’) === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;

After this line, add:
$isShellDisabled = true;

this is ok????